# How to use the same JS for same HTML multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used this from another stackoverflow question: http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/3410/ to create circle progress bars.

Except when I'm trying to create more then 1, nothing happens how can you clean fix this without copying the JavaScript and change just 1 var.

This is my code:

```css
.circleWrapper {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
.circleText {} .circleTextSmall {} #graph div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
#graph canvas {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#graph span {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#graph input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circleWrapper">
  <div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="50"></div>
  <div class="circleText">HTML/CSS</div>
  <div class="circleTextSmall">Small text</div>
</div>

<div class="circleWrapper">
  <div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="45"></div>
  <div class="circleText">PHP</div>
  <div class="circleTextSmall">Small text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
for(var i=0; i < els.length; i++){

    var el = els[i];

    var options = {
        percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
        size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
        lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
        rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = options.percent + '%';
    
    if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
        G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

    el.appendChild(span);
    el.appendChild(canvas);

    ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
    ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

    //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
    var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

    var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
     };

    drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
    drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
}
```

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    margin:80px;
    width:220px; height:220px;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
}

span {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="chart"  data-percent="88"></div>
<div class="chart"  data-percent="78"></div>
```

Comment: This could be cleaner, for example as posted by Luke Briggs

Answer (score 3):

## Use functions

Put your code inside a function which accepts some way of identifying a particular element, then call that function multiple times. [Here's a fork of that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuedL0xx/) as a working example:

```
function startGraph(el) { // turn it into a function which accepts an element
  
  // (Nothing else has changed)
  var options = {
      percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
      size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
      lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
      rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

  if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
      G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
  }

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

  el.appendChild(span);
  el.appendChild(canvas);

  ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
  ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

  //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
  var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

  var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
      percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
          ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
      ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
      ctx.stroke();
  };

  drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
  drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
}
```

Assuming each element has `class="chart"` then you can get all the elements and call the function with each one:

```
// Get all charts:
var myCharts=document.getElementsByClassName("chart");

// For each one..
for (var i in myCharts) {
   // Start it:
   startGraph(myCharts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is nice and clean

Answer (score 2):

You have used the `graph` ID twice.
You can only use an ID once per document.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

More information on this can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

Change the ID to something else and change the JS to interact with both elements.

This can for example be done with `getElementsByClassName()`. This function returns an array of elements instead of a single element.

I think it is best if you wrap all your functionality in a function with the following signature:

```
function startGraph(el) {
    ...
}
```

and then call the function from this for-loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    startGraph(elements[i]);
}
```

More information on that can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: var el = document.getElementsByClassName('chart'); // get canvas when i change my code to that nothing works anymore :(

Comment: @NickAudenaerde That is because `getElementByClassName()` returns an array of elements rather than a single element. You are going to have to loop over the array to do all the interactions with all elements

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to define **unique** ids in your `HTML`, and define an array of all your graph elements and loop through the logic, see this as an example:

```js
var elements = [{
  'id': 'graph1'
}, {
  'id': 'graph2'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elements[i]['id']);
  var options = {
    percent: el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

  if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
  }

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

  el.appendChild(span);
  el.appendChild(canvas);

  ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
  ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

  //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
  var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

  var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
    percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
  drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);

}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
}
span {}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph1" data-percent="88"></div>
<div class="chart" id="graph2" data-percent="25"></div>
```

Comment: Usage of `getElementsByClassName()` is better since one would be able to add more graphs without having to change the elements array that your solution uses.

Comment: @yarwest I totally agree :)